# Insert HTML into iFrame at caret (IE)

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

How would I insert HTML into an iFrame in IE? In chrome and firefox I used execCommand insertHtml, but it's not supported in IE.

I figured out how to paste html into a content editable div using pasteHTML, but I cant figure out how to insert into an iFrame.

The frame is within a page acting as a text-area, so design mode is on.

```
iframe id="editor" name="editor" class="theframe" onkeydown="enter(this,event)" onpaste="return handlepaste(this, event)"></iframe>
```

Comment: Does the iFrame have the identical URL domain as the containing document where your Javascript is?  If not, read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).

Comment: Which IE version? Please show, how your pages are constructed. What is the element you want to insert HTML?

Comment: IE 9+ preferably, but even just 11 is better than nothing.
And yes the iFrame has an identical URL as the domain containing the document where the Javascript is.

Comment: I wish to insert an image <img src=""> at the position of the caret.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
$("iframe").contents().find("body").html('my_new_content');
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to do this with pure Javascript, or only with jQuery? Also does this replace everything else thats already in it, or just insert?

Comment: Most certinly since jQuery is javascript. But I'm probably not the right person to write a pure javascript example